# Is there a paper wallet generator for the new bech32 bc1xxx segwit address?

Tags: segregated-witness, paper-wallet, bech32-address

Is there a paper wallet generator like bitaddress.org for the new bech32 bc1xxx segwit addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create printable ones using the *memory paper wallet* here: https://xcubicle.github.io/memorypaperwallet/

Pics: https://www.xcubicle.com/memory-paper-wallet-bitcoin-ethereum-monero-ardor-litecoin

[image]

Answer (score 2):

https://kimbatt.github.io/btc-address-generator/
You can generate bech32 segwit, p2sh-segwit, and legacy addresses here.
I made this site because I couldn't find any paper wallet generators that support bech32 format. Source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Kimbatt/btc-address-generator).

Comment: Hello, welcome to Bitcoin! Please just note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)